# Tabs not being removed by heredoc

Tags: bash, xargs, here-document

I'm trying to use heredoc with wget using the following code:

```bash
xargs wget <<-EOF
    https://example\
    .com
    EOF
```

[Replit link](https://replit.com/@vcdf/DiligentPowerlessBlogs)

(yes, I'm already using tabs as required by heredoc)

But for some reason, the tabs are not removed, causing wget to treat each line as a separate input

But if I eliminate all the tabs:

```bash
xargs wget <<-EOF
https://example\
.com
EOF
```

[Replit link](https://replit.com/@vcdf/LeftSmoggyTutorial)

It works as expected.
What am I doing wrong here? Is `xargs` the cause to this issue?

Comment: This seems like a clear "don't do that, then" problem of your own making.   Don't format your URLs with extraneous characters that are going to cause a problem.   and if you insist on doing that, or if the URLs comes pre-broken from some other source, then write the code needed to un-break them.

Answer (score 2):

The backslash "acts" first and concatenates the lines. The code becomes:

```bsh
xargs wget <<-EOF
    https://example .com
    EOF
```

(There are tabs, not spaces in the actual code; it's a pity [the site shows spaces](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5797/108618). In particular the character between `example` and `.com` is supposed to be tab.)

Then leading tabs are removed. The tab character that ends up in the middle of the line is not removed.

Comment: Ah, I see. Is there any alternative methods or some ways to circumvent this behavior?

Comment: @whatthe I know no easy method. I considered few ideas but they got cumbersome quickly and/or introduced other problems. I'm not saying there is no solution. I'm saying I don't know any. If I were you I would not split the line; or I would remove the "leading" tab from before `.com`.

Comment: Why do you need both a heredoc AND trailing antislashes? It does not make much sense.